# MS Project 2013: Summary task not showing duration correctly

Tags: ms-project

I am working on MS Project 2013. The summary task No. 6 is not showing the duration correctly. Refer to the picture below.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Due to link decay and blockers, please include sufficient information in the Question itself in order to allow an answer. That is, explain in words what the problem is (or include the picture directly in the Question as an attachment, not a link).

Answer (score 2):

Summary task 6, Building Town planning, contains three unlinked subtasks of durations 200d, 300d, and 476d - all of which start concurrently.  The duration of the summary task, at 476d, is exactly as expected - i.e. the difference between its start and finish dates according to the applicable calendar.  Summary start and finish dates are rolled up from the subtasks.  Since all the subtasks start at the same time, the summary's finish date and duration are both determined by the longest subtask - 476d.